# Why does an bool out variable get cleared when i return?

Tags: c#

I have a routine as follows , in a helper class

```
if (HelperClass.CheckFileExists(filename, out bool fileexists)
```

I have a global variable in my call file

```
 private bool fileexists= false;
```

But when the above call returns the fileexists , it is set to true , and then after i exit the calling routine it is set to false;
Why would this happen ?

Comment: because of variable scopes (C# basics) ... remove `bool` so you will use field instead local variable

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [it's easy to image ....](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fN6342)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out bool fileexists` declares a *new* variable called `fileexists`, which "hides" the global variable as long as the new variable is in scope.

If you want to refer to an existing variable or field, use `out fileexists` (without the data type) instead:

```
if (HelperClass.CheckFileExists(filename, out fileexists)) ...
```

---

As a side note, it looks like you don't *need* an out parameter in this case: If your helper method does what its name suggests, the following code:

```
fileexists = HelperClass.CheckFileExists(filename);
if (fileexists) ...
```

might be more readable and avoids returning the same value both as a return value and as an out parameter.